# With Google Cloud Function creating thumbnail of video with sub dir path

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, thumbnails

I am uploading Videos by rest api into google Cloud bucket and add one function to generate thumbnail with python. Code working on main directory but my video's uploaded in sub/sub/ directory so my code is not working.

```
import os
from google.cloud import storage
from subprocess import check_output
from videoprops import get_video_properties

client = storage.Client()
def hello_gcs(data, context):
  
  print(context)
  print(data)

  if data['contentType'].startswith('video/'):

     bucket = client.get_bucket(data['bucket'])
     name = data['name']
    
     file_name = '/tmp/'+ name
     print(file_name)

     thumbnail_file_name = '/tmp/' + name.split('.')[0] + '.jpg'
     print(thumbnail_file_name)

     try:
          os.remove(file_name)
     except OSError:
          pass

     try:
          os.remove(thumbnail_file_name)
     except OSError:
          pass

     print("File has been removed")

   
     blob = bucket.get_blob(name)
     blob.download_to_filename(file_name)

     print("Video Downloaded")

     props = get_video_properties(file_name)

     

     if os.path.exists(file_name):
          print("NEW MP4 EXISTS")            
          check_output('ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i '+file_name+' -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s '+str(props['width'])+'x'+str(props['height'])+' '+thumbnail_file_name, shell=True)
          thumbnail_blob = bucket.blob('thumbnail.jpg')
          thumbnail_blob.upload_from_filename(thumbnail_file_name)
     else:
          print("MP4 not created")
         
     print("uploaded")

  else :
     print("Not a Video")
```

So im only accessing tmp but not able to create folder like /tmp/Upload/Video/232/video.mp4.

Thanks
Dharmesh

Comment: Hello Dharmesh, welcome to Stack Overflow, I am a bit confused by your question, here is what I understood. currently your video is being uploaded into your bucket's '/tmp' directory and you want to upload it to a subdirectory of that, is that correct? Does that subdirectory already exists or do you need to create it with you code? If it does exist, does the thumbnail uploads correctly?

Comment: This function i have set on Event when Video upload complete so my videos always upload in sub dir so need to access and update. so i  have correct my code so ill upload when someone need.

Comment: Thanks!. Below code is working fine but next step is add watermark in video so its not working and crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my code for sub dir videos can generate thumbnail and upload in same dir.

```
    import os
from google.cloud import storage
from subprocess import check_output
from videoprops import get_video_properties

client = storage.Client()


def hello_gcs(data, context):
  
  print(context)
  print(data)

  if data['contentType'].startswith('video/'):

     bucket = client.get_bucket(data['bucket'])
    
     name = data['name']
     os.makedirs('/tmp/'+os.path.dirname(name), exist_ok=True) 
     file_name = '/tmp/'+ name
     print(file_name)

     thumbnail_file_name = '/tmp/' + name.split('.')[0] + '.jpg'
     print(thumbnail_file_name)

     try:
          os.remove(file_name)
     except OSError:
          pass

     try:
          os.remove(thumbnail_file_name)
     except OSError:
          pass

     print("File has been removed")

   
     blob = bucket.get_blob(name)
     blob.download_to_filename(file_name)

     print("Video Downloaded")

     props = get_video_properties(file_name)

     

     if os.path.exists(file_name):
          print("NEW MP4 EXISTS")            
          check_output('ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i '+file_name+' -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s '+str(props['width'])+'x'+str(props['height'])+' '+thumbnail_file_name, shell=True)
          thumbnail_blob = bucket.blob(os.path.dirname(name)+'/thumbnail.jpg')
          thumbnail_blob.upload_from_filename(thumbnail_file_name)
      
     else:
          print("MP4 not created")

     
     print("uploaded")

  else :
     print("Not a Video")
```

### **Requirement.txt**

- google-cloud-storage
- get-video-properties